# How to put the button on the bottom, when screen shrinks?

Tags: html, css, button

When I shrink the screen (mobile version), the button covers other elements (keyboard).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Le4xc.png)

Code:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Wisielec</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styl_2.css">
    <script src="mechanika2.js" defer></script>
    <script src="mechanika2.2.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="game-modal">
        <div class="content">
            <img src="#" alt="gif">
            <h4>Przegrana!</h4>
            <p>Poprawna odpowiedz to: <b>rainbow</b></p>
            <button class="play-again">Losuj następne</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="hangman-box">
            <img src="#" draggable="false" alt="hangman-img">
            <h1>Pacjent</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="game-box">
            <ul class="word-display"></ul>
            <h4 class="hint-text">Wskazówka: <b></b></h4>
            <h4 class="guesses-text">Pomyłki: <b></b></h4>
            <div class="keyboard"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
   <div class="button_div">
        <a href="index.html">
            <button class="centered-button">Powrót</button>
        </a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap");
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}
body {
    display: flex;
    padding: 0 10px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-image: url('pierwsze.jpg');
    background-size: cover; 
    background-position: center; 
}
.container {
    /*position: absolute;*/
    display: flex;
    width: 850px;
    gap: 70px;
    padding: 60px 40px;
    background: #bcaeae;
    border-radius: 10px;
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: space-between;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.hangman-box img {
    user-select: none;
    max-width: 270px;
}
.hangman-box h1 {
    font-size: 1.45rem;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.game-box .word-display {
    gap: 10px;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.word-display .letter {
    width: 28px;
    font-size: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
}
.word-display .letter.guessed {
    margin: -40px 0 35px;
    border-color: transparent;
}
.game-box h4 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.game-box h4 b {
    font-weight: 600;
}
.game-box .guesses-text b {
    color: #ff0000;
}
.game-box .keyboard {
    display: flex;
    gap: 5px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-top: 40px;
    justify-content: center;
}
:where(.game-modal, .keyboard) button {
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: #5E63BA;
}
.keyboard button {
    padding: 7px;
    width: calc(100% / 9 - 5px);
}
.keyboard button[disabled] {
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
:where(.game-modal, .keyboard) button:hover {
    background: #8286c9;
}
.game-modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    z-index: 9999;
    padding: 0 10px;
    transition: opacity 0.4s ease;
}
.game-modal.show {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
    transition: opacity 0.4s 0.4s ease;
}
.game-modal .content {
    padding: 30px;
    max-width: 420px;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.game-modal img {
    max-width: 130px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.game-modal img[src="images/victory.gif"] {
    margin-left: -10px;
}
.game-modal h4 {
    font-size: 1.53rem;
}
.game-modal p {
    font-size: 1.15rem;
    margin: 15px 0 30px;
    font-weight: 500;
}
.game-modal p b {
    color: #5E63BA;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.game-modal button {
    padding: 12px 23px;
}

@media (max-width: 782px) {
    .container {
        flex-direction: column;
        padding: 30px 15px;
        align-items: center;
    }
    .hangman-box img {
        max-width: 200px;
    }
    .hangman-box h1 {
        display: none;
    }
    .game-box h4 {
        font-size: 1rem;
    }
    .word-display .letter {
        margin-bottom: 35px;
        font-size: 1.7rem;
    }
    .word-display .letter.guessed {
        margin: -35px 0 25px;
    }
    .game-modal img {
        max-width: 120px;
    }
    .game-modal h4 {
        font-size: 1.45rem;
    }
    .game-modal p {
        font-size: 1.1rem;
    }
    .game-modal button {
        padding: 10px 18px;
    }
}



.centered-button {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    font-size: 50px;
    background-color: orange;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .centered-button:hover {
    background-color: red; 
    transform: scale(1.1); 
  }

  .container {
    /*position: absolute;*/
    display: flex;
    width: 850px;
    gap: 70px;
    padding: 60px 40px;
    background: #bcaeae;
    border-radius: 10px;
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: space-between;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

  .button_div {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px; /* Adjust the distance from the bottom as needed */
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
```

Full code:

GitHub:
https://github.com/andrzejhnatiuk/github.com-gramedyczna-gramedyczna.github.io/tree/main/index.html

Website:
https://andrzejhnatiuk.github.io/github.com-gramedyczna-gramedyczna.github.io/index.html/gra2.html

I tried to fix it by @media (max-width: 782px) adding extra margin to .button_div, change posiotion, but its usually put the button on the right or did nothing.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: You should specify a position relative with the absolue positionning. Why dont wrap your .button_div in wrapping div and give it a position relative

Comment: When I did it, the button goes in random place.

Comment: Also actualy you Can remove the button inside the a tag, just saw that no need to have a button inside a tag. Then style your a tag as button

Comment: I fixed a bit, but I want button lower, more down. I want the keyboard be available immediately, to not swipe the screen down to see the keyboard. How can I do this? GitHub: https://github.com/andrzejhnatiuk/github.com-gramedyczna-gramedyczna.github.io/tree/main/index.html

Website: https://andrzejhnatiuk.github.io/github.com-gramedyczna-gramedyczna.github.io/index.html/gra2.html

Comment: I'm not quite following what you want the layout to be. On small viewports there may not be room for both the keyboard and the stuff above it. I don't see how the keyboard can always be 'immediately available'.